# Laravel 7 error while using Stored Procedures :-SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to use stored procedures calls in Laravel which would perform the CRUD operations based on the action type passed as one of the arguements. However, I get an error. The complete error is shown here

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXEC my_stored_procedures(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1 (SQL: EXEC my_stored_procedures(INSERT,0,Pulak,Satpathy,pulak@gmail.com,$2y$10$ruH7V/z7nTNbjXVsQR8AOe2JmrlaPe5duiYIjA1poQxAH1MFi4OZ2,9999099990,1992-10-01,Male,BBSR,India,2020-09-25,11:55:36 ))
```

In this case,I am trying to `insert` data into the database obtained from a FORM page.

Here is the MySQL code -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `my_stored_procedures`(IN actiont VARCHAR(100),IN id_key BIGINT(200),IN first VARCHAR(500),IN last VARCHAR(500),IN em VARCHAR(500),IN pass VARCHAR(500),IN mob BIGINT,IN dob DATE,IN gen VARCHAR(10),IN addr VARCHAR(500),IN cot VARCHAR(500),IN time TIMESTAMP(6))
BEGIN
    DECLARE rowno BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    IF actiont="INSERT" THEN
       
                INSERT INTO users( 
                        first_name,
                        last_name,
                        email,
                        password,
                        mobno,
                        dob,
                        gender,
                        address,
                        country,
                        TIME_STAMP
                                )
                        VALUES (first,last,em,pass,mob,dob,gen,addr,cot,time);
                        
        
    ELSEIF actiont="UPDATE" THEN
    
    UPDATE users
    SET
    first_name=first,
    last_name=last,
    email=em,
    password=pass,
    mobno= mob,
    dob =dob,
    gender= gen,
    address= addr,
    country= cot,
    updated_at= time
    WHERE id=id_key;
    
    ELSEIF actiont="SELECT" THEN
    
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=id_key;
    
    ELSEIF actiont="DELETE" THEN
    
    DELETE FROM users
    WHERE id=id_key;
    
    ELSE 
    SELECT ("invalid");
    
    END IF;
END
```

And the Controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Newuser;

class NewUserRegnController extends Controller
{
       public function submitNewRegn(Request $request){
     
    $first_name         =   $request->first_name;
    $last_name          =   $request->last_name;
    $email              =   $request->email;
    $password           =   Hash::make($request->password, [
                                     'memory' => '1024',
                                     'time' =>  '2',
                                     'threar' =>  '2',
                                    ]);
    // $confirm_password    =   $request->confirm_password;
    $mobno              =   $request->mobno;
    $dob                =   $request->dob;
    $gender             =   $request->gender;
    $address            =   $request->address;
    $country            =   $request->country;
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
    $time               =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ");

      
    $act =  "INSERT";

    DB::select('EXEC my_stored_procedures(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), array($act,0,$first_name,$last_name,$email,$password,$mobno,$dob,$gender,$address,$country,$time));
   
      }

}
```

Also, if there is any other kind of error or bad coding, please let me know as well.

Comment: it seems there is not EXEC function in mysql. You should use CALL

Comment: oh! It worked. Another answer in Stack overflow stated the use of EXEC to use Stored procedures in laravel, so I used EXEC.

Comment: Btw,can you mention it as an answer,so that I can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Giacomo M
I had to use `CALL` instead of `EXEC`. Seems like `EXEC`  does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this line

```
$time               =   date("Y-m-d,H:i:s ");
```

to be this:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

I think comma in your date format makes sql try to write two values instead of one. here, from the error you get:

```
,India,2020-09-25,11:55:36 ))
```

Comment: I found the problem. It was pointed out by  @Giacomo M.